# How to do multiple exclude commands using itertools.chain in Django?

Tags: python, django, orm, iteration, python-itertools

Suppose I wanna run the exclude command repeatedly getting variables from exclude_list e.g. ['aa', 'ab' 'ac'].

I can do that using a loop:

```
for exclude_value in exclude_list:
     myQueryset.exclude(variable__startswith=exclude_value)
```

However, I'd like to do that using the itertools.chain command as I've read it is capable of doing so. Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you read? That seems like an overly complex way to do it for no improvement.

Comment: I've got recommendations to use itertools.chain from multiple sources, was wondering if that's something people practice. I'm not very experienced with Django.

Comment: I'd very much like to see those sources so I can understand you, however, I see no issue with your current setup as my answer below explains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is the correct approach - except for one small detail, you aren't retaining the excludes. [Django querysets are lazily evaluated, so running through a loop and continually chaining won't do anything](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), right up until you try to access something from the set.

If you do this:

```
qs = MyModel.objects
for exclude_value in exclude_list:
    qs = qs.exclude(variable__startswith=exclude_value)

qs = None
```

The database is *never hit*.

So do this:

```
qs = MyModel.objects
for exclude_value in exclude_list:
    qs = qs.exclude(variable__startswith=exclude_value)

qs.count() # Or whatever you want the queryset for
```

and you should be fine, if/when you are experience database slowdown, which ill likely be because of the large number of freetext expressions in a query, then do some profiling, then you can find an efficiency.

But I'd wager the above code would be sufficient for your needs.